# Cmake error: execution of make failed

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, uhd

I'm currently trying to build https://github.com/EttusResearch/uhd , https://kb.ettus.com/Building_and_Installing_the_USRP_Open-Source_Toolchain_(UHD_and_GNU_Radio)_on_Linux . Like it says in the instruction I execute `cmake ../`. But the command fails with following error

> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>   CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gmake" "cmTC_3ef51/fast"
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- broken
>   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
>     The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++" is not able to compile a simple test
>     program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: /home/.../uhd/host/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gmake"
>     "cmTC_3ef51/fast"
>
> Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was:
>     "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gmake" "cmTC_3ef51/fast"
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:27 (PROJECT)

Can someone help me with that?

best regards

Comment: 250 Q/A when searching for `broken CMake` . Did you look at any of them? Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/gmake looks like a wrong path, make should be in /usr/bin/make on ubuntu

Most likely you are missing
`apt-get install make`

Comment: make is already installed and up to date. Also gmake is a softlink to make.. Maybe I need to change the path manually?

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: Something bent around your paths. Simply reverse that.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?
My PATH variable does indeed contain /usr/share/bash-completion/completions but it also contains /usr/bin before 
I'm not sure what's your point

Comment: it shouldn't be there, these are not executables

Comment: Sorry, but what shouldn't be where?

Comment: There is a program 'make' in /usr/bin/ and a script 'make' in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions (target of the softlink 'gmake', which is also in this directory). So at some point things are getting mixed up?

Comment: yes, if you look at the script, you see it contains functions, that are sourced from other bash script, it is not meant to be executed on its own

Comment: I created a softlink 'gmake' within /usr/bin/ to 'make', but the error still occurs. It's really confusing since '/usr/bin' comes before '/usr/share/bash-...' in $PATH

Comment: /usr/share/bash-completion should not be in your PATH

Comment: did you rerun cmake after changing your path?

Comment: Ok, I just have removed the whole repository, downloaded it again and rerun cmake and now it works ... almost. Instead of the old error I get a new one: 
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_dea66.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_dea66 -rdynamic -lpthreads 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It is libpthread, so there is an s too much in the library name

Comment: Can you please give me a hint where I need to make a change? I've never worked with cmake before...

Comment: actually I think the libpthreads thing should be non-fatal, so maybe the error is something else?

Comment: I created a new question, where I posted the total error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511064/cmake-error-on-ubunut-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lpthreads?noredirect=1#comment72160347_42511064